# Presigned URL for S3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a resigned url for a s3 folder containing more than 1000 parquet files. The intension is to share these files to a resource external to the company.

Bucket location is in "US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1"

I have created a predesigned url with the following command from the cloud shell : `"aws s3 presign s3://bucket-name/large-folder/ --expires-in 604800 --region us-east-1"`

When I try to use the URL on the browser, I see that it is downloading a single zero byte file with the name of "large-folder".

How can I download all files in the folder which I want to share ?

PS: If I try to do the same exercise at a file level, it is working fine.

Comment: You can't. Pre-signed URLs are for individual objects. Options are to pre-sign as many URLs are there are objects or share temporary STS credentials with the client that allow access to the objects with prefix `large_folder/`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the AWS documentation, [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

> A presigned URL uses security credentials to grant time-limited permission to download objects.

If you want to provide access to all the files in the s3 bucket for a limited period, you can setup a temporary STS credentials with the third party.